# Ubuntu 16.04 extends past monitor edges: No resolution dropdown

Tags: 16.04, display, monitor, display-resolution

When I am on the desktop of the Ubuntu 16.04, the screen extends past my monitor edges, so I cannot reach the places that are off-screen. When I go into display settings and try to change the resolution, there is no dropdown bar under resolution. The only resolution is offers is 640 x 480 (4:3) I've tried going into the monitor settings as well, but nothing is working. My graphics card is a Zotac geforce gtx 1060 3gb. My monitor is a Philips 4000 series LED-LCD TV. The connection from the PC to the monitor is HDMI. Hope that this information helps you answer my question.

Comment: What graphics card? What monitor? What connection (VGA, HDMI, DVI, DP, ...)? Please edit your answer and add that info. Thanks.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Okay I included the details that you asked for

Answer (score 0):

Brand new hardware requires brand new drivers. The default open-source `nouveau` driver for Nvidia cards you're using isn't enough for a brand new GTX1060.

According to [Nvidia](http://www.geforce.com/drivers) this card is currently supported in the proprietary drivers versions 367 and 370.

**Do not install the Nvidia binary. Install from the [Graphics Drivers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) (tested for Ubuntu).**

In terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

After adding the PPA and updating the software sources, the driver will be available for your convenience in the Additional Drivers (search Dash for 'drivers').

Select and apply Nvidia 370.

Reboot.